# Creating sequence of dates in a column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, seq

I am having a data frame in R as follows:

```
df <- data.frame("Type" = c("Item A","Item B"), "Frequency" = c("Quarterly","Other"), "Date" = as.Date(c("2021-02-05","2021-05-05")),"endDate" = as.Date("2021-12-12"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I am trying to generate the sequence of dates between `Date` and `endDate` as each row. I am using the code below to generate the sequence

```
df <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(id = 1:nrow(df),deliveryDate = ifelse(
    df$Frequency == "Quarterly", list(seq(as.Date(df$Date), as.Date(df$endDate), by = "3 month")),
    ifelse(df$Frequency == "Monthly", list(seq(as.Date(df$Date), as.Date(df$endDate), by = "month")),
           ifelse(df$Frequency %in% c("Other"),list(seq(as.Date(df$Date), as.Date(df$Date), by = "month")),df$Date)))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(deliveryDate) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Type) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(deliveryNumber = row_number()) %>%
  dplyr::select(deliveryNumber,Type, Frequency, deliveryDate) %>%
```

TO be more descriptive, the sequence of date will be generated based on the frequency of the type. So to handle that case, I used `dplyr::mutate()`.

But I am getting an error as follows:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `deliveryDate`.
x 'from' must be of length 1
ℹ Input `deliveryDate` is `ifelse(...)`.
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue in R? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

You should consider a named vector:

library(tidyverse)

```
vec<-c(Quarterly = "3 months", Other = "month")

df %>% 
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(deliveryDate = list(seq(Date,endDate, by = vec[Frequency]))) %>%
   unnest(deliveryDate)

# A tibble: 12 x 5
   Type   Frequency Date       endDate    deliveryDate
   <chr>  <chr>     <date>     <date>     <date>      
 1 Item A Quarterly 2021-02-05 2021-12-12 2021-02-05  
 2 Item A Quarterly 2021-02-05 2021-12-12 2021-05-05  
 3 Item A Quarterly 2021-02-05 2021-12-12 2021-08-05  
 4 Item A Quarterly 2021-02-05 2021-12-12 2021-11-05  
 5 Item B Other     2021-05-05 2021-12-12 2021-05-05  
 6 Item B Other     2021-05-05 2021-12-12 2021-06-05  
 7 Item B Other     2021-05-05 2021-12-12 2021-07-05  
 8 Item B Other     2021-05-05 2021-12-12 2021-08-05  
 9 Item B Other     2021-05-05 2021-12-12 2021-09-05  
10 Item B Other     2021-05-05 2021-12-12 2021-10-05  
11 Item B Other     2021-05-05 2021-12-12 2021-11-05  
12 Item B Other     2021-05-05 2021-12-12 2021-12-05
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `complete`

```
df %>% group_by(Type) %>% mutate(DeliveryDate = Date,
                                 Frequency = case_when(Frequency %in% "Quarterly"~ "quarter",
                                                       Frequency %in% "Monthly" ~ "month",
                                                       Frequency %in% "Weekly" ~ "week",
                                                       TRUE ~ "month")) %>%
  complete(DeliveryDate = seq.Date(Date, endDate, by = Frequency)) %>%
  fill(Frequency, Date, endDate)

# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   Type [2]
   Type   DeliveryDate Frequency Date       endDate   
   <chr>  <date>       <chr>     <date>     <date>    
 1 Item A 2021-02-05   quarter   2021-02-05 2021-12-12
 2 Item A 2021-05-05   quarter   2021-02-05 2021-12-12
 3 Item A 2021-08-05   quarter   2021-02-05 2021-12-12
 4 Item A 2021-11-05   quarter   2021-02-05 2021-12-12
 5 Item B 2021-05-05   month     2021-05-05 2021-12-12
 6 Item B 2021-06-05   month     2021-05-05 2021-12-12
 7 Item B 2021-07-05   month     2021-05-05 2021-12-12
 8 Item B 2021-08-05   month     2021-05-05 2021-12-12
 9 Item B 2021-09-05   month     2021-05-05 2021-12-12
10 Item B 2021-10-05   month     2021-05-05 2021-12-12
11 Item B 2021-11-05   month     2021-05-05 2021-12-12
12 Item B 2021-12-05   month     2021-05-05 2021-12-12
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. It's not clear what you want for "Other" as opposed to "month", so I set it here to "week".

Note that you don't need to reference the data frame when using `mutate()` since everything called in the function is set to the environment of the data frame. Also, look into using `case_when()` instead of using nested `ifelse()` calls.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Frequency2 = case_when(Frequency == "Quarterly" ~ "3 month",
                                Frequency == "Month" ~ "month",
                                TRUE ~ "week")) %>% 
  group_by(Type, Frequency2) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(middates = map2(data, Frequency2, ~ seq.Date(min(.x$Date), max(.x$endDate), by = .y))) %>% 
  unnest(c(data, middates)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 36 x 6
   Type   Frequency Frequency2 Date       endDate    middates  
   <chr>  <chr>     <chr>      <date>     <date>     <date>    
 1 Item A Quarterly 3 month    2021-02-05 2021-12-12 2021-02-05
 2 Item A Quarterly 3 month    2021-02-05 2021-12-12 2021-05-05
 3 Item A Quarterly 3 month    2021-02-05 2021-12-12 2021-08-05
 4 Item A Quarterly 3 month    2021-02-05 2021-12-12 2021-11-05
 5 Item B Other     week       2021-05-05 2021-12-12 2021-05-05
 6 Item B Other     week       2021-05-05 2021-12-12 2021-05-12
 7 Item B Other     week       2021-05-05 2021-12-12 2021-05-19
 8 Item B Other     week       2021-05-05 2021-12-12 2021-05-26
 9 Item B Other     week       2021-05-05 2021-12-12 2021-06-02
10 Item B Other     week       2021-05-05 2021-12-12 2021-06-09
# ... with 26 more rows
```