# Use dplyr to aggregate counts by month from start-stop ranged variables?

Tags: r, date, dplyr

Let's say I have school enrollment data stored in this format, with start date and end date fields:

| unique_name | enrollment_start | enrollment_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amy | 1, Jan, 2017 | 30, Sep 2018 |
| Franklin | 1, Jan, 2017 | 19, Feb, 2017 |
| Franklin | 5, Jun, 2017 | 4, Feb, 2018 |
| Franklin | 21, Oct, 2018 | 9, Mar, 2019 |
| Samir | 1, Jun, 2017 | 4, Feb, 2017 |
| Samir | 5, Apr, 2017 | 12, Sep, 2018 |
| ... | ... | ... |

And I want to produce aggregated counts of enrollment by month like this:

| month | enrollment_count |
| --- | --- |
| Jan, 2017 | 25 |
| Feb, 2017 | 31 |
| Mar, 2017 | 19 |
| Apr, 2017 | 34 |
| May, 2017 | 29 |
| Jun, 2017 | 32 |
| ... | ... |

Is there an easy way to accomplish this with dplyr?

The only way I can think to do this is by looping over a list of all months from range month_min to month_max to count the number of rows with start or stop dates that fall inside each month. Hoping for easier code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post what you have tried. It's easier to help

Comment: could you also share your data in a more user friendly format with `dput()` ?

Comment: You could start with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65377773/5325862), creating a sequence of dates for each row, then unnesting. Then extract the month & year from each data and aggregate

Comment: I didn't know about dpu(), thanks @Mike. I will try to do that in future questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be done pretty elegantly with the [clock](https://clock.r-lib.org) and [ivs](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/index.html) packages. You seem to want monthly counts, so you can use the year-month type from clock. And ivs is a package dedicated to working with *intervals* of data, which is exactly what you have here. Here we assume that if your enrollment start/end fell in a month, then you should be considered active in that month.

```r
library(ivs)
library(clock)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

enrollments <- tribble(
  ~unique_name, ~enrollment_start, ~enrollment_end,
  "Amy",        "1, Jan, 2017",    "30, Sep, 2018",
  "Franklin",   "1, Jan, 2017",    "19, Feb, 2017",
  "Franklin",   "5, Jun, 2017",    "4, Feb, 2018",
  "Franklin",   "21, Oct, 2018",   "9, Mar, 2019",
  "Samir",      "1, Jan, 2017",    "4, Feb, 2017",
  "Samir",      "5, Apr, 2017",    "12, Sep, 2018"
)

# Parse these into "day" precision year-month-day objects, then restrict
# them to just "month" precision because that is all we need
enrollments <- enrollments %>%
  mutate(
    start = enrollment_start %>%
      year_month_day_parse(format = "%d, %b, %Y") %>%
      calendar_narrow("month"),
    end = enrollment_end %>%
      year_month_day_parse(format = "%d, %b, %Y") %>%
      calendar_narrow("month") %>%
      add_months(1),
    .keep = "unused"
  )

enrollments
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   unique_name start        end         
#>   <chr>       <ymd<month>> <ymd<month>>
#> 1 Amy         2017-01      2018-10     
#> 2 Franklin    2017-01      2017-03     
#> 3 Franklin    2017-06      2018-03     
#> 4 Franklin    2018-10      2019-04     
#> 5 Samir       2017-01      2017-03     
#> 6 Samir       2017-04      2018-10

# Create an interval vector, note that these are half-open intervals.
# The month on the RHS is not included, which is why we added 1 to `end` above.
enrollments <- enrollments %>%
  mutate(active = iv(start, end), .keep = "unused")

enrollments
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   unique_name             active
#>   <chr>         <iv<ymd<month>>>
#> 1 Amy         [2017-01, 2018-10)
#> 2 Franklin    [2017-01, 2017-03)
#> 3 Franklin    [2017-06, 2018-03)
#> 4 Franklin    [2018-10, 2019-04)
#> 5 Samir       [2017-01, 2017-03)
#> 6 Samir       [2017-04, 2018-10)

# We'll generate a sequence of months that will be part of the final result
bounds <- range(enrollments$active)
lower <- iv_start(bounds[[1]])
upper <- iv_end(bounds[[2]]) - 1L

months <- tibble(month = seq(lower, upper, by = 1))
months
#> # A tibble: 27 × 1
#>    month       
#>    <ymd<month>>
#>  1 2017-01     
#>  2 2017-02     
#>  3 2017-03     
#>  4 2017-04     
#>  5 2017-05     
#>  6 2017-06     
#>  7 2017-07     
#>  8 2017-08     
#>  9 2017-09     
#> 10 2017-10     
#> # … with 17 more rows

# To actually compute the counts, use `iv_count_between()`, which counts up all
# instances where `month[i]` is between any interval in `enrollments$active`
months %>%
  mutate(count = iv_count_between(month, enrollments$active))
#> # A tibble: 27 × 2
#>    month        count
#>    <ymd<month>> <int>
#>  1 2017-01          3
#>  2 2017-02          3
#>  3 2017-03          1
#>  4 2017-04          2
#>  5 2017-05          2
#>  6 2017-06          3
#>  7 2017-07          3
#>  8 2017-08          3
#>  9 2017-09          3
#> 10 2017-10          3
#> # … with 17 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Create a list column containing the sequence of months between each set of dates, then unnest and count.

Notes:

1. I use `lubridate::floor_date()` to round `enrollment_start` to the first day of the month. Otherwise, `seq()` may skip months if `enrollment_start` is on the 29th of the month or later.
2. The fifth row of your example data has `enrollment_start` later than `enrollment_end` -- I assumed this was an error and removed.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

enrollments %>% 
  mutate(
    across(c(enrollment_start, enrollment_end), dmy),  # convert to date
    month = map2(
      floor_date(enrollment_start, unit = "month"),    # round to 1st day
      enrollment_end,
      ~ seq(.x, .y, by = "month")
    )
  ) %>% 
  unnest_longer(month) %>% 
  count(month, name = "enrollment_count")

#> # A tibble: 27 x 2
#>    month      enrollment_count
#>    <date>                <int>
#>  1 2017-01-01                2
#>  2 2017-02-01                2
#>  3 2017-03-01                1
#>  4 2017-04-01                2
#>  5 2017-05-01                2
#>  6 2017-06-01                3
#>  7 2017-07-01                3
#>  8 2017-08-01                3
#>  9 2017-09-01                3
#> 10 2017-10-01                3
#> # ... with 17 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This was beautiful, thank you. Wouldn't have thought to do it this way at all. Very simple

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this with `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

1. Pivot the data creating multiple rows per student and format your dates.
2. group on student and generate missing months using `complete`.
3. group on the generated periods and count.

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c('enrollment_start','enrollment_end')) %>%
    mutate(value = as.Date(value, format =  "%d, %B, %Y")) %>%
    mutate(value = lubridate::floor_date(value, 'month')) %>%
  
#   unique_name name             value     
#   <chr>       <chr>            <date>    
# 1 Amy         enrollment_start 2017-01-01
# 2 Amy         enrollment_end   2018-09-30
# 3 Franklin    enrollment_start 2017-01-01
# 4 Franklin    enrollment_end   2017-02-19
#   ..etc.

  group_by(unique_name) %>%
  complete(value = seq.Date(min(value), max(value), by="month")) %>%
  arrange(unique_name, value) 

enrollment_count <- group_by(data, value) %>%
  count()
```

Edit: I forgot to floor the dates in order to properly aggregate per period at the end. Added `floor_date` from `lubridate` to do this.